# Running bash variables as system argument for python script

Tags: python, bash, variables, arguments

Every is in the tittle I need to run python script called from a Bash script.
In order to make it more 'user friendly' (my colleagues would like to use it). I want to define variable at the top of my code, that can be used by my python code as a sys.argv[], like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
var1 = "file1 file2 file3"
var2 = "filemod1 filemod2 filemod3"

python sortout.py var1 var2
```

It appears that it takes me the var1 as a file and it does not replace it by the variable's value.

Many greetings,

Félix

Comment: You want to review both the duplicates; you have two separate errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to access to the content of the defined variables, done with the dollar sign.

```
python sortout.py "${var1}" "${var2}"
```

Comment: Thank you this works out perfectly

Comment: Then accept the answer to symbolize it to other users, please.

Comment: Ok done, I didn't figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$` sign for having access to bash variable
e.g

```
>fval=3
>echo $fval
>3
```

Refer link [Bash Variable](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html) in case of any detail needed